# Copy ( to clipboard ) only one required column contents of html data table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My requirement is simple. 
I have a table with four columns. Have some mobile numbers in 2nd column "Mobile No.". I just want to copy ( to clipboard ) All the mobile numbers in the "**Mobile No.**" column on button click. 
Tried some javascript samples for the same, not worked as required. Please give some suggestions.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<button id="copy-table-button" data-clipboard-target="#datatable">  Copy Mobile No. </button>
  
<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Sl No</th>
    <th>Mobile No.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
    <td>Maria</td>
    <td>Active</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2223330</td>
    <td>Ruma</td>
    <td>Active</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3334440</td>
    <td>Kumar</td>
    <td>Not-Active</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>44455500</td>
    <td>Subba</td>
    <td>Active</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>555666111</td>
    <td>Orayyo</td>
    <td>Not-Active</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>555666111</td>
    <td>Orayyo</td>
    <td>Active</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>555666111</td>
    <td>Orayyo</td>
    <td>Not-Active</td>
  </tr>
  
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I just need to copy them as plain text, to paste in other websites or forms.
Should paste like this after copy..

```
1234567890
2223330
3334440
44455500
555666111
555666111
555666111
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The navigator api should give you what you're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard

Comment: In what format do you want to copy that data? Should it be plain text? Or html? Could you show an example of what the copied data would look like after pasting? Also, how can you access the data you need to copy? Is it only available in your markup? If yes, can you edit your markup to make accessing data from it easier?

Comment: @anonDelta They are only mobile numbers in that column. I just need to copy them as plain text, to paste in other websites or forms. Edited my Question with required output details.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, let me know if you have any troubles with it:

```
const copyButton = document.querySelector('#copy-table-button');

const copyToClipboard = (_) => {
  const dataElements = document.querySelectorAll('tr > td:first-child + td');
  const data = Array.from(dataElements).map(element => element.textContent).join('\n');
  const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain'});
  const clipboardItem = new ClipboardItem({'text/plain': blob});

  navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItem]);
}

copyButton.addEventListener('click', copyToClipboard);
```